# How to implement Entity Framework transcript store on Twitter Adapter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, botframework

I am using the [Entity Framework transcript store](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/EntityFrameworkTranscriptStoreExample) for saving my chat transcripts on bot framework 4, it works great on direct line and emulator but when I add the [Twitter adapter](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Adapters.Twitter) the bot answers the user but it doesn't store anything from this channel,

I discovered that when I use the method:

```
((TwitterAdapter)_adapter).ContinueConversationAsync(_appId, conversationReference, BotCallback, default(CancellationToken))
```

it stores outgoing messages but still not saving incoming ones,

How can I store both incoming and outgoing messages?

Comment: Just want you to know that we're tracking this. I've been working on this here and there the last couple of days but am having trouble getting it working without rewriting the whole adapter. Hoping you get it answered [here](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/issues/141)

Comment: Thanks @mdrichardson-MSFT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last update of the twitter adapter it is working now, please refer to [this answer](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/issues/141#issuecomment-530035364),
basically it says that in the Startup.cs file, in the ConfigureServices Method you must have this:

```
 var store = new EntityFrameworkTranscriptStore(connection);
            services.AddSingleton<ITranscriptStore>(store);
```

and the Configure method must be something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ITranscriptStore transcriptLogger)
      {
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
          {
              app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
          }
          else
          {
              app.UseHsts();
          }

          app.UseDefaultFiles();
          app.UseStaticFiles();

          //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
          app.UseMvc();
          app.UseTwitterAdapter();

          app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<TwitterAdapter>().Use(new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(transcriptLogger));
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more for others, than anything.

The core of this issue is that the Twitter Adapter overwrites others. Since Entity Framework Transcript Store uses the `AdapterWithErrorHandler`, the Twitter Adapter wouldn't allow it to be called.

[A PR was submitted](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/149) to address this and also bring the Twitter Adapter more in line with the code style of other Bot Framework Adapters. As soon as that PR gets merged in, this will work.

Comment: Yes, I will wait for the merge